# In 2013 Designer Workflow, getting single item from a list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, list-item, workflow-designer

Is it possible to fetch a single item from a list (not the current list or item) without making an HTTP service call. If not, then why? Don't you think it should be something readily available. I can see an action that allows you to update a list item, then why not something as simple as retrieving an item?

Comment: Well, if it helps, you can get the column values from a single list item and assign it to workflow variables or use it for other actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is what do you really need? Getting an item does you no good, unless you want information from the item, or want to change the item. You found how to change an item. To get fields from an item, you would use the lookup and select whichever list you'd like, which field from that list, and the "WHERE" clause, so to speak. You can only specify one field so you can't, for example, find the item where the Title is "My Title" and the Created Date is 4/13/2016. Additionally, if there are multiple items that match, it will return only the first item it finds that matches.

Comment: how are you going to get an item from a  list (mind you, not the "Current" item or list) using the item ID? Do you have any examples over the web that you can cite? All this without making the service call.

Comment: Let's say that you want to get the title of an item in another list where the item's ID = 2. Using the `Set Workflow Variable` action, click on "value" and then formula (fx) button. From Data Source, select your other list. For Field From Source, select Title. In the next section for Field, select "ID" and for Value, type "2." This will return the title of the other list's item. Repeat for any other fields you want.

Comment: Makes sense! Indirect though, but answers my question. Thanks very much!